# How to Prompt the user to press Enter to Exit in terminal so that the terminal doesn't close automatically?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, terminal

Here is my Port.sh file

```
echo 'Give me a maximum of 5 seconds to run please.'
lsof -i | grep Xvnc | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $USER
lsof -i | grep $USER | grep Xvnc | grep -o -P '(?<=:).*(?=->)'
echo 'Brought to you by a cloudy and unlucky day.'
echo 'Press enter to exit'
```

I would like to make the terminal wait for the user to press enter after the last echo before closing.

All of the users on my ubuntu desktop environment have the terminal set to close after the script is done.

Can anyone tell me what i can do to make the terminal wait for the user to press enter.

I have google searched and nothing relevant came up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add at the end of your script:

```
read junk
```

---

See [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) for more info.

Comment: thats it? nothing else? if so then thanks and i kinda feel stupid x.x

Comment: You don't even need `junk`, `read` on its own is sufficient.

Comment: I thought it would be much harder than that x.x . 
This is what i get for thinking about it too hard.Thanks guys

Comment: From Bash manual: _If  no  names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY._

Comment: thx @madneon i will be marking this as the answer in 3 minutes